# PHP method strtotime is not resulting well

Tags: php

```
function DateFormat($dt)
{
    return $newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($dt));
}
$cr='2014-02-31';
echo DateFormat($cr);


Input: $cr='2014-02-31';
Output: 03/03/2014
```

I am passing `2014-02-31` and getting output `03/03/2014`.
Please help me out.

Comment: Since when feb have 31 days? The result seems right to me since PHP is calculating the error for you `31-28=3`.

Comment: $cr='2014-02-31'; here date format is same (YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: Oh!! Thanks alot Mr Prix... :D .. Lot of laugh...

Comment: what do you think all, should here strtotime() must show an error to come out of it?

Comment: @RajaRassani No, see my answer as to why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP's date functions work with *dates* not *strings*. And that's an important distinction. Strings are just a bunch of characters in a specified order. Dates have months, days, years, hours, minutes, seconds, timezones, etc. When PHP works with dates it takes all of them into consideration.

So when you pass Feb 31 to a PHP date function it is going to try to make sense of it as a date and not a string. This means it isn't just going to take that date cut it up into bits and then rearrange them as you are expecting. It is going to turn that date into a date representation it can work with and then manipulate it.

As we all know, February does **not** have 31 days. As a result of the invalid date, PHP is trying to be helpful and taking three days after last day in February of that year (since Feb only has 28 days this year) and giving you that date.

Comment: +1: With the update, this became a very good answer, explaining the issue in (somewhat) detail.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is February most years only has 28 days.  2/31 would be logically translated to 3/3.  On a leap year you'd get 3/4...

The `strtotime()` method as it needs to be very flexible to be able to handle stuff without borking like:

```
 strtotime('2014 February + 31 day - 1 year');
```

And no I don't think it should error out.  When you have a well formed date string, PHP has a deceptively named  method called `checkdate()` you could use:

```
   $crappy_date='2014-02-31';
   $date_parts =  explode('-', $crappy_date);
   $valid = checkdate($date_parts[1], $date_parts[2], $date_parts[0]);
```

Comment: I like your "logically" translated. In what way can it be logical if it's totally invalid ? Can PHP logically translate for me this `$x = 1/0` ?

Comment: @BabyAzerty strtotime is meant to parse whatever crazyness out of a string and try and make a timestamp for it, not to validate the string provided (even if it looks like a date).  There's a php function `checkdate()` meant for checking the validity of a date

Comment: Yes sir. I like and am satisfied. Thanks :)